# How to create newline in a rebol block?

Tags: rebol

let's say I have a config.txt which contains:

> "param11" "param12"
>
> "param21" "param22"

I'll load it in memory with

```
config: load %config.txt
```

I can save it back with

```
save %config.txt config
```

So far so good. Now the problem occurs for me when I want to add

> "param31" "param32"

I have tried

```
append config reduce [newline "param31" "param32"]
save %config.txt config
```

But that doesn't give the expected result

> "param11" "param12"
>
> "param21" "param22"
>
> "param31" "param32"

but this instead

> "param11" "param12"
>
> "param21" "param22" #"^/" "param31" "param32"

So how to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fork's said load/save is for Rebol readable data. Read/Write is for general use.

```
write/append %config.txt reform [newline "param31" "param32"]
```

will work in your case. %config.txt is still loadable.

Answer (score 3):

We know that:

```
[a
 b]
```

and

```
[a b]
```

...are treated the same as Rebol "source code", they describe identical data structures.  We also know that Rebol is *reflective* and can read and write its code/data format with LOAD and SAVE.

Yet this raises the question: If you LOAD a source file with a newline in it... and then SAVE it... will there be a line break in the output?  Or will it be forced into a canonical format?

*(For a bit of crazy background on the LOAD and SAVE wackiness, read [my debate with BrianH](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Talk:The_Invariants_of_Rebol#TO-STRING_vs._MOLD_vs._FORM)...where you see me making a solid case and him brushing me off as per usual.  It's frustrating to be at odds with the "gurus", however clever they may be. :P)*

In any case, you must realize that Rebol is trying to be clever.  There's a binary "new-line" bit which is hiding behind the scenes, do `help new-line` and you'll see:

```
USAGE:
    NEW-LINE block value /all /skip size

DESCRIPTION:
Sets or clears the new-line marker within a block. (Modifies)
NEW-LINE is a native value.

ARGUMENTS:
block -- Position in block to change marker (block!)
value -- Set TRUE for newline

REFINEMENTS:
/all -- Set/clear marker to end of block
/skip -- Set/clear marker periodically to the end of the block
    size (integer!)
```

So if you want to play the Rebol source code game, and use LOAD and SAVE, you must invoke this API to inject a "new-line" bit onto `param22`.  But realize that if your data must fit a non-Rebol-source wire format (or be read by human readers with certain expectations) then you're using the wrong functions.  You need to do rank-and-file serialization with `read` and `write`.

Comment: Never heard of new-line will be usefull anyhow and
Will read wiki this week-end seems funny :)

Answer (score 1):

NOT RIGHT: write/append %config.txt reform [newline "param31" "param32"]

Answer #1 isn't quite right. Here's the result when looking at the text file with an editor app:

```
"param11" "param12" 

"param21" "param22"

param31 param32
```

---

Here's the result upon loading the file after the write/append:

```
>> write/append %config.txt reform [newline "param31" "param32"]

>> a: load %config.txt

== ["param11" "param12"

    "param21" "param22"

    param31 param32

]
```

---

Thus param31 and param32 are not saved as strings but as words.

```
>> first a

== "param11"

>> type? first a

== string!

>> fifth a

== param31

>> type? fifth a

== word!
```

---

RIGHT: write/append %config.txt reform [newline mold "param31" mold "param32"]

```
>> write/append %config.txt reform [newline mold "param31" mold "param32"]

>> b: load %config.txt

== ["param11" "param12"

    "param21" "param22"

    "param31" "param32"

]

>> type? b/5

== string!
```